Некорректный вывод данных в чат-приложении
Вопрос по поводу работы с приложением чата на react + react router с одной стороны и node js, socket.io с другой стороны.
Начнем с того, что userHandler получает переданные ему параметры при регистрации пользователя при помощи socket.emit.
Вот код userHandler:
import { JSONFilePreset } from "lowdb/node";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
const users = {users: []}
const db = await JSONFilePreset('db/users.json', users)

db.update((userInit) => {
    userInit.users.push( {
        email: 'name1gmail.com',
        username: 'name1',
        userId: nanoid(8),
        roomId: 123
    })
})


const socketHandler = (jwt,socket) => {
        const token = socket.handshake.auth.token 
          try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, '111')
            socket.handshake.auth.id = decoded.id;
            socket.handshake.auth.email = decoded.email; 
            socket.handshake.auth.roomId = decoded.roomId
          }
          catch (err) {
            console.error('ошибка аутентификации', err )
            socket.disconnect()
          }

}


const userHandler = (jwt,socket) => {
    function emailHandler(params) {
      
      const infoToken = {
        id: params.userId,
        username: params.username,
        email: params.email,
        roomId: params.roomId
      }
      
      const secretKey = '111'
      
      const createTokenFunc = (infoToken, secretKey) => {
        const tokens = jwt.sign(infoToken, secretKey,{expiresIn: '1h'})
        return tokens
      }
      
      socket.emit('start', createTokenFunc(infoToken,secretKey))
      socketHandler(jwt,socket)
      
            db.update((usersFinal) => {
                usersFinal.users.push({
                    ...params, 
                })
            })
         db.write()
                
                console.log('Пользователь подключился:', socket.handshake.auth.roomId)
                socket.join(`room-${socket.handshake.auth.roomId}`)
                console.log('user connected')
    }
    socket.on('email', emailHandler)
}



export default userHandler  

Здесь срабатывает событие start, которое передаёт токен через функцию, и затем должна выполняться функция socketHandler(jwt,socket), в которой будет декодироваться токен.

Проблема заключается в том, что он выводит в строке 'Пользователь подключился:' id предыдущей комнаты.
Вот код с клиентской части, где токен добавляется в локальное хранилище:
import {Main} from "components/Main";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";



export function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(`token-${count === 1 ? count : count + 1}`); 

    const newSocket = io('http://localhost:3001', {
      auth: {
        token: token,
      },
    });

    newSocket.on('start', (tokens) => {
      const newCount = count + 1;
      setCount(newCount);
      localStorage.setItem(`token-${newCount}`, tokens); 
    });

    setSocket(newSocket);

    
    return () => {
      newSocket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [count]);

  

  return (
    <Main socket={socket}/>
  );
}

